# jquery touchstart delay, much more than mousedown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a simple game using DOM elements. I need a div (containing an image) to move as soon as the user taps on the screen. Using mousedown works perfectly, but touchstart has a very noticable delay - making it unusable for a quick reaction game.

How can I reduce this delay?

My code:

```
_myScreen.on('touchstart mousedown', function(){screenClicked();});


function screenClicked(e) {
    var y = e.offsetY;
    model.css({top:y});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 300ms delay on touch devices. Here's a [blog post](http://www.icenium.com/blog/icenium-team-blog/2013/11/21/what-exactly-is.....-the-300ms-click-delay) from TJ VanToll of Icenium team explaining the history of this behavior and potential solutions for it.

An excerpt from the post:

> While browsers have come up with some interesting solutions to the
>   300ms click delay, there is simply no solution that works everywhere.
>   However, there are plenty of smart people that have thought about this
>   problem and have come up with JavaScript based solutions for all
>   platforms. These solutions can be categorized into two camps -
>   polyfills for the pointer events model and "fast click" solutions.
>
> Let's look at some pointer event polyfills first. Pointer Event
>   Polyfills
>
> There a several polyfills out there for pointer events. Here are the
>   more popular ones.
>
> ```
> Polymer from Google
> HandJS from Microsoft
> Points by @Rich-Harris
> ```
>
> ...
>
> FastClick is a small library developed by FT Labs that specifically
>   aims to prevent the 300ms click delay in mobile browsers.

- https://github.com/Polymer/PointerEvents
- http://handjs.codeplex.com/
- https://github.com/Rich-Harris/Points
- https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

Comment: Thanks! Fastclick is working for click events, which solves my problem. Touchstart is still delayed however.